# repo/git revert to state as one month ago

Tags: git, android-source, repository

I'm working with `AOSP` sources which were downloaded by `repo` command    (http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html)

Now I need to get all repository as it was 1 month ago.
I found here solution (http://alexpeattie.com/blog/working-with-dates-in-git/):
`git revert master@{"1 month ago"}`

But I can't do it in AOSP source tree.
I tried to do it with:
`repo forall -c git revert master@{"1 month ago"}`
But it's not working because there is no `master` branch for all `git` repositories in AOSP `repo`.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first of all, find the commit hash you want to revert to :

```
git log --pretty=oneline --since="2013-08-26"
```

you can change the date if you want

you'll get all commit from this date to today
the last one in the list will be the one you want

Then :

```
git reset --hard 0845f5de..... // this need to be the hash you got previously
```

Hard will change your working directory and your index to the version of the commit while moving the current branch to this commit

Use it precautionously !!! You will loose your current change to the working directory